# Magento 2: Load multiple categories by category ids

Tags: magento2, category

Hi i want to load multiple categories in Magento 2.3.
 but it only fetch 1st category of a subcategory, not rest of category.

```
$categories = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load(3,4,5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code to get of a subcategory to 1st level category

```
protected $_registry;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,      
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
) {
    $this->_registry = $registry;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getCurrentCategory()
{
    return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
}

public function getLevel1Category(){
    if($this->getCurrentCategory()){
        if($this->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategories()){
            foreach ($this->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategories() as $parent) {
                if ($parent->getLevel() == 1) {
                    // reurns the level 1 category id;
                    return $parent->getId();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always avoid use the ObjectManager directly on your code. You can use the below methods in your code to get the category and sub-categories data

```
protected $categoryRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
) {
    $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
}

public function getCategoryName()
{
    $categoryId = '43';
    $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
    $categoryName = $category->getName();
    return $categoryName;
}
```

> For getting first level categories, you can use below code

```
$parent_category_id = 3;
$parentCategory = $this->categoryRepository->get($parent_category_id);
$subcategories = $parentCategory->getChildrenCategories();
foreach($subcategories as $subcategory) {
    echo $subcategory->getName();
}
```

> For 2nd level categories, you can use below code

```
$parent_category_id = 3;
$parentCategory = $this->categoryRepository->get($parent_category_id);
$subcategories = $parentCategory->getChildrenCategories();
foreach($subcategories as $subcategory) {
    echo ' = '.$subcategory->getName().'<br/>';
    if($subcategory->hasChildren()) {
        $childCategoryObj = $this->categoryRepository->get($subcategory->getId());
        $childSubcategories = $childCategoryObj->getChildrenCategories();
        foreach($childSubcategories as $childSubcategory) {
            echo ' == '.$childSubcategory->getName().'<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```